# How to get previous date in Perl Script

Tags: perl

How can I get previous date from current date, I have below chunk of code. kindly help out.

Need in this format: eg: `07/16/2015`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$current_date = `date +"%m/%d/%Y"`;
$current_date = substr($current_date,0,-1);

print $current_date, "\n";
```

Comment: You can use the [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/~stbey/Date-Calc-6.4/lib/Date/Calc.pod) Module for that.

Comment: Yes, you could use Date::Calc. But why would you when `time`, `localtime` and Time::Piece are all in a standard Perl distribution? :-)

Comment: @SagarH: Can I interest you in a rational date format - like 2015-07-16?

Answer (score 4):

This is easy with [localtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html).

This gives the date (and time) 24 hours ago. This might not be the previous day at around the switch to or from daylight saving time.

```
use constant ONE_DAY => 24 * 60 * 60;
say scalar localtime time - ONE_DAY;
```

To control the format, use `POSIX::strftime`.

```
use POSIX 'strftime';
use constant ONE_DAY => 24 * 60 * 60;
my @then = localtime time - ONE_DAY;
say strftime '%Y-%m-%d', @then;
```

For more complex date and time handling, I'd reach for [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) or [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime).

Comment: I believe it's best to use `24 * 60 * 60` than the magic `86_400`. But well done for the underscore separator

Comment: @Borodin: Shame it confused SO's syntax highlighter :-/

Comment: Sorry if you disagree Dave. Your rollback coincided with my edit. Fell free to do it again!

Comment: I can see why you'd add the parentheses (although they are unnecessary). But I don't understand why you'd replace an ISO standard date format with a ludicrous middle-endian one :-)

Comment: Because the OP says *"Need in this format: eg: 07/16/2015"*. And `localtime time - ONE_DAY` looks very like `localtime(time) - ONE_DAY` to my eye

Comment: Well we certainly don't want to encourage that kind of insanity!

Comment: I agree, but I understand that there are countries that our missionaries haven't reached yet

Comment: Lets call it a draw with the battle of edits. See you tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want *yesterday's* date?

The `Time::Piece` module is in core, and is very much smaller than `DateTime`

The code looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_DAY';

my $yesterday = ( localtime() - ONE_DAY )->mdy('/');

say $yesterday;
```

#### output

```
07/15/2015
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.20/lib/DateTime.pm) module:

```
use DateTime;

my $date = DateTime->today;
$date->subtract( days => 1 );

print $date->mdy('/'), "\n";
```

Comment: `DateTime->today` uses `DateTime->now` which returns a time in the UTC zone. You need to provide the optional named parameter `time_zone => "local"` to the `->today` constructor, otherwise the resulting date could be ±14 hours away from the OP's intended date depending on the local zone.

Answer (score 2):

Using perl core modules,

```
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $t = localtime() - ONE_DAY;
print $t->mdy("/"), "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a system call for that. Perl has it built in. One way to do it is with [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/search?q=DateTime).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use DateTime;

my $yesterday = DateTime->today->subtract( days => 1 )->mdy('/');

say $yesterday;
```

Comment: `DateTime->today` uses `DateTime->now` which returns a time in the UTC zone. You need to provide the optional named parameter `time_zone => "local"` to the `->today` constructor, otherwise the resulting date could be ±14 hours away from the OP's intended date depending on the local zone.

Answer (score 0):

Today's Date is 07/16/2015

```
use strict;
use DateTime;
my $date = DateTime->now->subtract( days => 1)->mdy('/');
```

Output Date is

```
07/15/2015
```

I hope you get the answer.

Comment: Yes I got expected date, now i need to pass date as the variable for sending an email in a mail body. i need to use date as dynamic while sending mail, my code is like below. i am getting date properly but getting error while sending mail.



#!/usr/bin/perl
my ($psec, $pmin, $phour, $pmday, $pmon, $pyear, $pwday, $pyday, $pisdst) = localtime(time() - 24*60*60);
$pyear += 1900;
$pmon  += 1;
$pmon = '0' . $pmon if $pmon < 10;
my $pdate = $pyear . '-' . $pmon . '-' . $pmday;
print  "$pdate\n"

Comment: perl /home/xyz/revenueReport/sendEmail -f alert@xyz.com -t xyz.adiga@xyz.com -u  Automated Revenue Report -m Dear All,"\n" Please find the attachment consisting the automated report for today : date +"%d-%m-%y" "\n" "\n" Best Regards "\n" Tech Support Team "\n" xyz technology  -a /home/xyz/revenueReport/conf/RevenueReport.xlsx -s smtp.xyz.com:25 -xu alert@xyz.com -xp password

Comment: If you have a new question, then post it as a new question.

Comment: How is your answer differ from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31447916/4752537) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31447900/4752537) answer?

Comment: `DateTime->now` returns a time in the UTC zone. You need to provide the optional named parameter `time_zone => "local"` to the constructor, otherwise the resulting date could be ±14 hours away from the OP's intended date depending on the local zone.

Comment: Hey Friend, I think you have problem in mail sending. So You need to check the module description which you are using for sending mail in CPAN. Where you can easily find what is the meaning of the error you are getting. which is -1, -2, -3 something like that.